# Clarinet mouthpiece suggestions for an adult learner

Tags: clarinet, mouthpieces

I am looking for a mouthpiece for my B♭ clarinet. I am an adult but have only been playing for a few months. I also play the recorder and have done so for about 5 years, and so I have some confidence with the recorder, which has helped me with the clarinet. I have about £80 maximum to spend. Any suggestions on this and anything else for a beginner would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to fuss over choosing a mouthpiece at your stage.  Use the standard one that came with the clarinet. If you've broken it, just go for ebonite with a medium tip.  You shouldn't have to spend as much as half of your £80. Choice of reed strength will make much more difference.

Comment: I agree. Unless your current mouthpiece is particularly broken and causing you trouble - I wouldn't expect you to see any noticable difference - save your money for something else.

Comment: I agree. Save your money for buying boxes of reeds. They break in a very short time in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

[Clark W. Fobes, Debut](https://www.clarkwfobes.com/collections/soprano-clarinet/products/debut-clarinet-mouthpiece?variant=6110309445)

An excellent mouthpiece that will serve you for years to come, and well below your price limit, although I don't know how they handle international shipping.